# values not being set from database information

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

How come when i load the page the information will not load into the fields? It gives me the correct amount of rows from the database but none of the actual information is shown or even set as the value

```
<?php 

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test") or die("could not connect");

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'update') {

$updateQuery = (" UPDATE `test1` SET f_name = '$_POST[f_name]', l_name='$_POST[l_name]', email='$_POST[email]' WHERE id='$_POST[id]'");
mysqli_query($link, $updateQuery);


};


$query = ("SELECT * FROM `test1`");
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

echo "<table border=1
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Email</th> 
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<form method="post" action="update.php">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="f_name" value="<?php $row['f_name'] ?>" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="l_name" value="<?php $row['l_name'] ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php  $row['email'] ?>"></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php  $row['id']  ?>"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" ></td>
</tr>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: how i could copy your code, first i replied this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget echo use the following

```
    <td><input type="text" name="f_name" value="<?php echo $row['f_name'] ?>" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="l_name" value="<?php echo $row['l_name'] ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo  $row['email'] ?>"></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php  echo $row['id']  ?>"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing the result here and because of that it is not displaying the values.

```
<td><input type="text" name="f_name" value="<?php echo $row['f_name']; ?>" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="l_name" value="<?php echo $row['l_name']; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php  echo $row['email']; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php  echo $row['id'];  ?>"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?php echo $row['f_name']; ?>` OR `<?=$row['f_name']?>` instead of `<?php echo $row['f_name']; ?>`